# HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) Where My page has a Master Page

Tags: jquery, ajax

Getting the error HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). (XHR)POST - http://localhost:57102/Abc.aspx/Details

script File :

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Web Method :

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static object Details()
{
   return "Hello";
}
```

Ajax Call :

```
function GetDetails() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Abc.aspx/Details",
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (_data) {
                    (JSON.stringify(_data));
                    _data = JSON.parse(_data.d);
                     alert(_data);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
```